# How to put characters beyond 9 in superscript in java?

Tags: java, math, superscript, binomial-theorem

So I am making a program in Java on a BlueJ environment that computes Binary expansion. However, I can't seem to figure out how to add powers more than 9 in the output.
If I have an input power of anything more than 9 the program goes haywire, presumably because there are no cases after 9.

Also, I personally feel my program in general is extremely inefficient but I just did it this morning and this was the first approach I saw, so if you see a way to make it more efficient than using switch case, that'd be great too.

This is my code so far. It's not all mine, but I'm not sure if intellectual property and stuff applies on here, so just putting it out there.

```
    import java.util.*;
    class Binomial_Theorem_Expansion
    {
        public static void main(String args[])
        {
        Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the value of x in (x+a)^n");
        int x=s.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter the value of a in (x+a)^n");
        int a=s.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter the value of n in (x+a)^n");
        int n=s.nextInt();
        System.out.println ("The expanded answer is");
        int r=0;
        int powx=n;
        while (r<=n)
            {
              long nCr=calculatenCr(n,r);
              if(nCr!=-1)

                 {
                    double y=Math.pow((double)x,(double)n-r);
                    double z=Math.pow((double)a,(double)r);
                    switch (powx) 
                          {
                            case 0: System.out.print ("("+nCr*y*z);
                            break;
                            case 1: System.out.print ("("+nCr*y*z+"x");
                            break;
                            case 2: System.out.print ("("+nCr*y*z+"x\u00B2");
                            break;
                            case 3: System.out.print ("("+nCr*y*z+"x\u00B3");
                            break;
                            case 4: System.out.print ("("+nCr*y*z+"x\u2074");
                            break;
                            case 5: System.out.print ("("+nCr*y*z+"x\u2075");
                            break;
                            case 6: System.out.print ("("+nCr*y*z+"x\u2076");
                            break;
                            case 7: System.out.print ("("+nCr*y*z+"x\u2077");
                            break;
                            case 8: System.out.print ("("+nCr*y*z+"x\u2078");
                            break;
                            case 9: System.out.print ("("+nCr*y*z+"x\u2079");
                            break;
                            case 10: System.out.print ("("+nCr*y*z+"x\u2071\u00B2");
                            break;
    }
    switch (r) {
        case 0: System.out.print (")"); 
        break;
        case 1: System.out.print ("y"+")");
        break;
        case 2: System.out.print ("y\u00B2"+")");
        break;
        case 3: System.out.print ("y\u00B3"+")");
        break;
        case 4: System.out.print ("y\u2074"+")");
        break;
        case 5: System.out.print ("y\u2075"+")");
        break;
        case 6: System.out.print ("y\u2076"+")");
        break;
        case 7: System.out.print ("y\u2077"+")");
        break;
        case 8: System.out.print ("y\u2078"+")");
        break;
        case 9: System.out.print ("y\u2079"+")");
        break;
    }
    r++;
    if (r<=n)
    {
                System.out.print ("+");
    }
    powx--;

}
}
    }
        public static long calculatenCr(int n,int r)
        {
                    long res=1;
                        if(n>=r)
                        {
                            res=getFact(n)/(getFact(n-r)*getFact(r));
                            return res;
                        }
                        else return -1;
                    }
                    public static long getFact(int n)
{
    long f=1;
    for(int i=n;i>=1;i--)
    {
    f*=i;
    }
return f;
}
}
```

Thanks for any constructive input. :)

Comment: [Unicode subscripts and superscripts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts)

Answer (score 2):

> presumably because there are no cases after 9.

Your code is using UNICODE superscript characters, and the cases that you have cover only numbers zero through ten for `x` and zero through nine for `y`.

You can fix this by defining a method that produces a superscript UNICODE conversion of a multidigit number, and calling it from both places where you need to produce such representation:

```
switch (powx) {
    case 0: System.out.print ("("+nCr*y*z);
        break;
    case 1: System.out.print ("("+nCr*y*z+"x");
        break;
    default: System.out.print ("("+nCr*y*z+"x"+toSuperscript(powx));
        break;
}
```

The other switch (i.e. `switch (r)`) should be converted in a similar way.

You can implement `String toSuperscript(int n)` by producing a decimal representation of `n`, and then replacing `'0'` with `'\u2070'`, `'1'` with `'\u00B9'`, and so on.